# How to apply a theme to a bootply project?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, themes, bootply

This maybe a naive question - but I am stuck.
I have created a simple (my first) bootply project.
One can access it here: http://www.bootply.com/sRefcMualY

I wish to "style" this bootstrap project using the free theme "Slate", available here:
http://bootswatch.com/slate/

I have had no success in "applying" the theme to my project! Copying the css into the css window works in design mode, but is rejected if I try and save it.

It must be something silly and easy - but I am stumped!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would download the `Slate` bootstrap.min.css, and use it replace the bootstrap.min.css in your project. For Bootply, it would be a matter of pointing to the Slate CSS. One way is to use CSS import:

http://www.bootply.com/nGTdpeesE2